I need help adjusting and aligning images
I would like to add 2 pictures at the bottom of the page; the one on the right is close to the margin, while the one on the left is right up to the edge of the page.I have tried \minipage and \tabular but I can't seem to get the right position that I want.
Here are the codes that I used:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images


\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{flushright}
    \textbf{\huge{SS XXX-X:YYYY}} \\
    \large{(ICS XX.XXX.XX; XX.XXX)}
\end{flushright}

\vspace{3cm}

\textbf{\Large{SINGAPORE STANDARD}} \vspace{1em}

\textbf{\Huge{SS XXX-X:YYYY}} \vspace{1em}

\huge{– Part X : Part title Xxxx} \vspace{2em}

\Large{Incorporating Amendment No. 1 and No. 2 } \vspace{1em}

\Large{Confirmed and classified as a mature standard YYYY }

\vfill

\begin{flushleft}

\includegraphics[width=5cm, height=4cm]{BigS.png}

\end{flushleft}

\begin{flushright}
     \includegraphics[scale=1]{SSC.jpg}
\end{flushright}

\end{document}

The first image is what I wanted. The second is what I have achieved so far.


Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the code which you tray so far.

Hi Zarko, here's the codes:
\begin{figure}[b]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Graphics/Red-S.png}

\end{minipage}
\hspace{8em}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{Graphics/SSC-logo.jpg}

\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

Kode should be in question, not in comment. Also it should be in form of small complete document, which we can compile as it is.

@Zarko Thank you for your input. I'll ask a new question with your suggestions.

You shouldn't have asked a new question. You can always edit a question and correct it. Since another question already includes MWE, you should delete this one. By the way, better if you use the images from the mwe package as examples. Any latex user already has those images, so they don't need to download anything to test the code.

You can use the textpos for this purpose. You must tune the values of the textblock environments for your images.
Note: \Large and \Huge have no arguments, there are superfluous curly braces in this code.


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[overlay,absolute]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{flushright}
    \textbf{\huge{SS XXX-X:YYYY}} \\
    \large{(ICS XX.XXX.XX; XX.XXX)}
\end{flushright}

\vspace{3cm}

\textbf{\Large{SINGAPORE STANDARD}} \vspace{1em}

\textbf{\Huge{SS XXX-X:YYYY}} \vspace{1em}

\huge{– Part X : Part title Xxxx} \vspace{2em}

\Large{Incorporating Amendment No. 1 and No. 2 } \vspace{1em}

\Large{Confirmed and classified as a mature standard YYYY }

\vfill

\begin{textblock}{12}(-5,19.5)
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{5}(14,22)
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{textblock}

\end{document}


